# Lookup row(s) with specific value through userform and copy/paste to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have made a userform with 8 textboxes. When a user fills out these textboxes a row is inserted with the different values in another sheet. (1 row, 8 columns).

I have made another userform identical to the "input" userform. The user should then be able to write one of the 8 values in this userform, and the VBA should then find all rows containing this value and copy the row(s) to a third sheet.

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks!

---

I have tried the following code, but it doesn't work:

```
Sheets("Rawdata").Select
FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
' Loop through each row
For x = 2 To FinalRow
'kommentar
        ThisValue = Cells(x, 1).Value
        If ThisValue = Me.TextBox1_1.Value Then
            Cells(x, 1).Resize(1, 33).Copy
            Sheets("Rapport").Select
            NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            Cells(NextRow, 1).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Sheets("Rawdata").Select
        ElseIf ThisValue = Me.TextBox2.Value Then
            Cells(x, 1).Resize(1, 33).Copy
            Sheets("Rapport").Select
            NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            Cells(NextRow, 1).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Sheets("Rawdata").Select
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

The code simply turns back with "Compile error: Variable not defined".

Please help

Comment: Thanks for adding the code, but you'll need to tell us what doesn't work. What do you observe versus what you expect and what you want?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Please see my edit.